# Opening and closing a hatch with different switches

Tags: arduino-uno, relay

I'm new to the whole Arduino thing and I'm not much of a programmer myself so I need some help...

The goal is to have 4 buttons which a person who operates it gives out different outputs from the motor connected too a hatch. The relays are connected to a hatchmotor with limit switches at both closed and fully opened positions.

My idea is like this:

- button1 = activates relay 1->opens the hatch,
- button2 = activates relay 2->closes the hatch,
- button3 = endless loop, opens and closes the hatch,
- button4 = deactivated both relay 1 and 2, and stops the loop.

My code so far:

```
const byte knappstangd(4); //limit switch, closed position
const byte knappoppen(5); //limit switch, open position
const byte brytareoppnalucka(6); //momentary switch for opening hatch
const byte brytarestangalucka(7); //momentary switch for closing hatch
const byte startaloop(8); //momentary switch for starting the "loop"
const byte stoppaloop(9); //momentary switch for stopping the loop.

const byte relastanga = 2; //activates relay 1 which closes the hatch
const byte relaoppna = 12; //activates relay 2 which opens the hatch

void setup()
{
    pinMode (knappstangd,INPUT);
    pinMode (knappoppen,INPUT);
    pinMode (brytareoppnalucka,INPUT);
    pinMode (brytarestangalucka,INPUT);
    pinMode (startaloop,INPUT);
    pinMode (stoppaloop,INPUT);


    pinMode (relastanga, OUTPUT);
    pinMode (relaoppna, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    if(digitalRead(brytareoppnalucka)==HIGH){       //if momentary switch brytareoppnalucka = 1 do this:
        digitalWrite (relaoppna, HIGH);             //open hatch
    }

    if(digitalRead(brytarestangalucka)==HIGH) {     //if momentary switchå brytarestangaluckan = 1 do this:
        digitalWrite (relastanga, HIGH);            //close hatch
    }

    if(digitalRead(stoppaloop)==HIGH) {             //if momentary switch stoppaloop=1 do this:
        digitalWrite (relaoppna, LOW);              //turn off relay for opening
        digitalWrite (relastanga, LOW);             //turn off relay for closing

        if(digitalRead(startaloop)==HIGH) {         //if momentary switch startaloop=1 do this:
            digitalWrite(relastanga, HIGH);         //start with closing the hatch to set a zero point

            if(digitalRead(knappstangd)==HIGH) {    //if limit switch knappstangd=1 do this:
                digitalWrite (relastanga, LOW);     //turn off Relay for closing
                delay (200);                        //wait 0,2 seconds
                digitalWrite (relaoppna, HIGH);     //turn on relay for opening
            }
            if(digitalRead(knappoppen)==HIGH) {     //if limit switch knappoppen=1 do this:
                digitalWrite (relaoppna, LOW);      //turn off relay for opening
                delay (200);                        //wait 0,2 seconds
                digitalWrite (relastanga, HIGH);    //turn on relay for closing
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to be aligned between the description and the source code, could you add what is the label of **button1**, **button2**, **button3** and **button4** ? Is **button1** equal `knappoppen(5);` or `knappstangd(4);` ?

Comment: Yeah the buttons equals the momentary switches.

Button 1 = brytareoppnalucka
button 2= brytarestangalucka
button 3= startaloop
button 4= stoppaloop

Sry for swedish involved in programming lol, makes sense in swedish

Comment: 1. What is the problem? 2. The switch is active high? How about your pull-down circuit?

Comment: 1. What i'm experiencing right now is that if i push button1, the relay1 for opening turns ON as intended but keeps being turned ON for some reason... All the other switches does not work at all... not even Button 3 which simply says turn both relay1 and relay 2 OFF.

2. If a switch is active it gives out HIGH input to the board. (Normally open).

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think, what you need is a 4th if statement that check if none of the buttons are pressed, and turns of all the relays. Or on turning on the "open-hatch" relay, you should add a while so it waits till the end-switch is triggered, so it can turn off the relay.

Comment: For the activity of "relay1" (`relaoppna`), you have defined a state to be `HIGH` when "button1" (`brytareoppnalucka`) goes to `HIGH`, but no condition to go back to `LOW`. Are you expected that the "button2" (`brytarestangalucka`) should do that simultaneously as rising "relay2" (`relastanga`) to 'HIGH` ?